# React(Typescript) FunctionComponent with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I am interested in how to add `InputComponents` Type on FunctionComponent while using `forwardRef` same time

```
interface InputComponents {
 InputNumber: typeof InputNumber;
}

const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
 (
     { label, className, prefix, suffix, disabled, error, 
 ...htmlInputProps },
   forwardedRef,
 ) => {
   const [inputHtmlId] = useState(uniqueId("__input_id_"));
   const localRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const focusInput = () => {
  localRef.current?.focus();
};
```

Comment: Please post your code as formatted code, not an image.

Comment: okay i will edit